# Query: Can we create workflow on workflow history list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, list, designer-workflow, workflow-history

Can we start a workflow on Workflow History list i am trying to create a workflow we have got a requirement to do so i was able to create a workflow and publish it but when i go to the list and start manually it does not seem to start?

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, we can create the workflow 2010 and 2013 in the workflow history list.

After you start the workflow, it will create the column for the workflow in the workflow history list like the picture below. The "app" is the workflow 2013, and the "approvel" is the workflow 2010.

You could check if there is column for the workflow started by you in the workflow history list.

[image]

Comment: thanks. Column is been created in my case but when i try to start the workflow it seems to start but no changes is been made on the workflow history list.I checked the workflow instances too i don't see any instance started and also tried re publishing the workflow but no luck.

Comment: You could just add log to history list action in the workflow,  publish and start the workflow to check if it will log message to workflow history list.